# Make an eclipse project from plugins

Tags: plugins, eclipse-rcp

i am making a java application using eclipse RCP.

i have build the project modules as separate plugin projects, now i want      to link them using a main plugin project where i have the menu.i don't know how to add plugin projects to the main one.

Can anyone help me please, how to add them and make connecting the views possible ?

Comment: Maybe what you are looking for is called a 'Product' in Eclipse. But you could also think of a 'Feature'. You should search for these within any RCP tutorial and clarify your question a bit.

Comment: i have been searching so adding my projects paths to the main project MANIFEST file won't solve my problem ?

Comment: You usually use a 'product' file to define the contents of a RCP - see http://www.vogella.com/tutorials/EclipseProductDeployment/article.html